# How do I do this page scrolling effect?

Tags: html, vertical-scrolling

On the website https://sourcetoyou.com/ it has a page scrolling effect. I am not sure if the site was using default bootstrap code or their own custom code.

I have tried searching for similar effects but I find my vocabulary lacking and I am not sure what how to properly search for it. Can anyone point me in the right direction or what I should be searching for?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: The guy is literally asking how to do more research, he is not asking for somebody to do his homework. I don't see the point of down voting. Yes, question is broad and maybe bad - but you have to start from somewhere.

Comment: @MiroslavSaracevic yet the explanation of a downvote is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I'd say that fits the bill here - it's not personal. Questions asking for a point in the right direction aren't helpful as the answers tend to be opinionated.

Comment: Also, the external website may not have the same "page scrolling effect" in the future, which will make the question obsolete to future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help. It is full page scrolling
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/vertical-and-horizontal-scrolling-with-fullpagejs--cms-24215
It uses library fullpage.js

Comment: Thank you so much, It is so hard to find things if you don't know the proper name. This is exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

css wise is also something really fancy going on called scroll snap module
check it out ;)
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scroll-snap-1/

unfortunately:
http://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-sna